# VB code for automatic refresh in arcmap with timer?

Tags: esri-geodatabase

We have a shapefile of electrial network.The SCADA data of the electrical network is stored in oracle 10g express edition.We have to link oracle table with the arcmap and automatically refresh the map with the values which will be updated in oracle table.Do suggest a method and a code to execute this in Arcmap

Answer (score 1):

You want to use either the [IActiveview::PartialRefresh](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/ArcGISEngine/arcobjects/esriCarto/IActiveView_PartialRefresh.htm) (efficient) or the [IActiveView::Refresh](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/ArcGISEngine/arcobjects/esriCarto/IActiveView_Refresh.htm) (highly inefficient) method. As far as the timer goes, it depends whether it is a [VB.NET Timer](http://www.dotnetperls.com/timer-vbnet) or [VB6/VBA Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zffx82xt%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)